# Search/ filter method for all attributes in my index table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, parameters

I'm trying to write a row for my index table that filters my objects regarding a specific value of a specific column. What I have until now is this:

`pimps_controller.rb`:

```
def index
  @pimps = Pimp.search(params[:search])
end
```

`pimp.rb`:

```
def self.search( search)   
    if search
        where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")     
    else  
        scoped   
    end
end
```

A part of view:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
```

That filters after the objects title only so I tried to alter it to make it functional for different search fields that can filter after different attributes. I want to pass a second parameter value if someone fires the search function to make sure it triggers for the right attributes. That's what I've tried:

`pimps_controller.rb`

```
@pimps = Pimp.search(params[:search_column],params[:search])
```

`pimp.rb`:

```
def self.search(search_column, search)   
    if search
        col = "%#{search_column}"
        s = "%#{search}%"
        where(col 'LIKE ?', s)   
    else  
        scoped   
    end  
end
```

The view:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], params[:search_column => title] %>
```

But it's not working. I get an error message for passing the both parameters in one search field I guess. How would you do it?

Comment: what error you are getting? and what do you mean by both params in one search field?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  It looks wrong. `<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], params[:search_column => title] %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple tutorial on how to do it:

https://we.riseup.net/rails/simple-search-tutorial

In the model, you will have to add the fields with or condition to the query.

```
def self.search(search)
  search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
  find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?', search_condition, search_condition])
end
```

If you want to define the field to search in the params you can use string interpolation with simple quotes:

%q(text contains "#{search.query}")

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 text fields, one for the column, one for the value:

```
# view
<%= text_field_tag :search_value, params[:search_value] %>
<%= text_field_tag :search_column, params[:search_column] %>

# controller
@pimps = Pimp.search(params[:search_column], params[:search_value])

# Pimp model
def self.search(search_column, search_value)   
  if search_value.present? && search_column.present?
    column = self.column_names.include?(search_column.to_s) ? search_column : 'title'
    value = "%#{search_value}%"
    where("#{self.table_name}.#{column} LIKE ?", value)   
  else  
    scoped   
  end
end
```

---

The problem about this method is that if you don't type the exact name of the column, it will search the value in the column `title`. I think you should use a `select_tag`, listing all searchable columns of the model:

```
# view
<%= select_tag :search_column, options_for_select(Pimp.column_names.map { |col| [col, col] }, params[:search_column]) %>
```

This view code will display a `select` tag with the available columns of the Pimp model. You can easily limit the searchable columns by defining a class method on Pimp:

```
# Pimp model
def searchable_columns
  self.column_names - ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
end

# view
<%= select_tag :search_column, options_for_select(Pimp.searchable_columns.map { |col| [col, col] }, params[:search_column]) %>
```